# How to extract numbers from a string using regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex

This little challenge just screams regular expressions to me, but so far I am stumped.

I have an arbitrary string that contains two numbers embedded in it. I need to extract those two numbers, which will be n and m digits long (n,m are unknown in advance). The format of the string is always

```
FixedWord[n digits]anotherfixedword[m digits]alotmorestuffontheend
```

The first number is of the format `1.2.3.4` (the number of digits varying) eg `5.3.20` or `5.3.10.1` or `5.4`.

and the second is a simpler 'm' digits (eg `25` or `2`)

eg `"AppName5.2.6dbVer44Oracle.Group"`

It shouts 'pattern matching' and hence "extraction using regexes". Can anyone guide me further?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern:

```
(\d+(?>\.\d+)*)\w+?(\d+)
```

Will match this:

```
AppName5.2.6dbVer44Oracle.Group
       \__________/   <-- match
       \___/     \/   <-- captures
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uS6cH4/1)

And will capture the two values you're interested in in capture groups.

Use it like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"(\d+(?>\.\d+)*)\w+?(\d+)");
if (match.Success)
{
    var first = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var second = match.Groups[2].Value;
    // ...
}
```

Pattern explanation:

```
(           # Start of group 1
  \d+       # a series of digits
  (?>       # start of atomic group
    \.\d+   #   dot followed by digits
  )*        # .. 0 to n times
)
\w+?        # some word characters (as few as possible)
(\d+)       # a series of digits captured in group 2
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for (and thanks to everyone else who pitched in to help in my hour of need!).  I don't need to use regexes as much as I would wish, so I'm perpetually a newbie on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\w*?([\d|\.]+)\w*?([\d{1,4}]+).*
```

Comment: Note that `\w` includes digits!

Answer (score 0):

You could start from the following:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+((?:\d+\.)+\d)[a-zA-Z]+(\d+).*$
```

I assumed that the fixed words are just made of letters and that you want to match the entire string. If you prefer, you could substitute the parts not in parentheses with the actual fixed words or change the character sets as desired. I recommend using a tool like https://regex101.com to fine-tune the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it basic by specifing a match `( )` by looking for a digit `\d`, then zero or more `*` digits or periods in a set `[\d.]` (the set is \d -or- a literal period):

```
var data    = "AppName5.2.6dbVer44Oracle.Group";
var pattern = @"(\d[\d.]*)";

// Outputs:
// 5.2.6
// 44
Console.WriteLine (Regex.Matches(data, pattern)
                        .OfType<Match>()
                        .Select (mt => mt.Groups[1].Value));
```

Each match will be a number within the sentence. So if the total set of numbers change, the pattern will not fail and dutifully report 1 to N numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply look for the numbers, since you only care for the numbers and don't want to check the syntax of the whole input string.

```
Matches matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+(\.\d+)*");
if (matches.Count >= 2) {
    string number1 = matches[0].Value;
    string number2 = matches[1].Value;
} else {
    // Less than two numbers found
}
```

The expression `\d+(\.\d+)*` means:

> `\d+`           one or more digits.
>   `( )*`         repeat zero, one or more times.
>   `\.\d+`       one decimal point (escaped with \) followed by one or more digits.

and

> `\d`            one digit.
>   `( )`          grouping.
>   `+`              repeat the expression to the left one or more times.
>   `*`              repeat the expression to the left zero, one or more times.
>   `\`              escapes characters that have a special meaning in regex.
>   `.`              any character (without escaping).
>   `\.`            period character (".").

Comment: `\.` full stop makes no sense, for it *doesn't stop a match operation*. Wouldn't it be better to say it is a literal period?

Comment: The Windows "Character Map" program calls this character "Full Stop". Call it "literal period" or "decimal point" or whatever you want.

Comment: Full Stop is the British term for the period [Full stop vs. period](http://grammarist.com/usage/full-stop-period/). It is not clear which side of the pond Neil is on....but I would warn US readers who would not know what a full stop is. :-)

Comment: `FULL STOP` seems to be the official unicode name for this character. See: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NamesList.txt  The description in this list says: `002E FULL STOP
 = period, dot, decimal point`

Comment: It's a full stop! Just like the paved strip to the side of the road is a pavement, water comes from a tap, we sit on the lavatory (not on John) and God is still an Englishman (although he possibly has a Green Card by now) :-).